# UIStackview horizontal alignment with 2 rows

Tags: uistackview

I've a horizontal stackview which has a stackview as a subview with 2 labels. Alignment & Distribution are set to Fill in Xcode Attribute Inspector.  I want to display 7 subview stacks inside the stack view with 4 in first row and 3 in second row using only one horizontal stackview.  I have loaded first row. When I add 5th element, it is appearing in 1st row instead of 2nd row. Number of subviews changes dynamically. If there are 3 elements it should only display only one row. If more than 5, it should display in 2 rows.Below is the code.

```
if let viewInfos = TestViewController.viewInfos{
            let dataNib = UINib(nibName: "InfoStackView", bundle: frameworkBundle)
            for viewInfo in viewInfos {
                let infoStackView = dataNib.instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! InfoStackView
                infoStackView.addInfoToStackView(viewInfo: viewInfo)
                self.InfoStackView.addArrangedSubview(infoStackView)
            }
        }

    Inside addInfoToStackView method, i add the label for each stackview
```

Above code adds stackview as subviews horizontally. I want to restrict 4 in first row and 3 in next row. Please help me how do this.

Comment: Best if you get started and come back if you get stuck on something.

Comment: @MattCremeens : I've already started. I have loaded first row. When I add 5th element, it is appearing in 1st row instead of 2nd row. No of subviews changes dynamically. If there are 3 elements it should only display only one row. If more than 5, it should display in 2 rows. Updated question. Thanks :)

Comment: In that case, would you mind posting your code?

Comment: `if let viewInfos = TestViewController.viewInfos{
   let dataNib = UINib(nibName: "InfoStackView", bundle: frameworkBundle)
   for viewInfo in viewInfos {
    let infoStackView = dataNib.instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! InfoStackView
    infoStackView.addInfoToStackView(viewInfo: viewInfo)
    self.InfoStackView.addArrangedSubview(infoStackView)
   }
  }`

Inside addInfoToStackView method, i add the label for each stackview

Comment: Great. I would suggest formatting it and placing it in your question and then mention what you expected that code to do and what it is doing instead.

Comment: @MattCremeens: Done

Comment: @MattCremeens: Can you please help now?.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is outside of my expertise. I just wanted to help you edit your question to maximize your chance of getting some help from others.